# R SQL Server odbc and DBI unicode table names

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-dbi

I have the following R code used to connect to a MS SQL Server.

My table and column names contains unicode characters. And they appear odd when written to the database from R.

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "driver=SQL Server;server=127.0.0.1;database=AdventureWorks;uid=xxx;pwd=abc;")    
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn, "TestTableÆØÅ", dataset)    
DBI::dbDisconnect(conn)
```

I've tried setting the `CharacterSet` and `charset` properties in the connection string but this is not helping.

How do i get R and DBI to write the correct tablenames and columns to the SQL Server.

My default R file encoding is UTF-8 and sessionInfo() lists `Danish_Denmark.125`

The actual data are written down fine with no encoding issues. Its the table and column names there is the issue.

Comment: `DBI::dbWriteTable(conn, "[TestTableÆØÅ]", dataset)`?

Comment: @lad2025 It still outputs a table name `dbo.[testaÃ¥Ã¸]`

Comment: I can write such a table just fine with `DBI:dbWriteTable`. However, I am unable to actually read it back in with `DBI::dbReadTable` with odbc_1.3.2  and DBI_1.1.1.